# PHP - Fill array with data - while loop in foreach loop results in an empty array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I get data from two or more mysql-querys - and want to write all the data-information I get from the different querys in the same array. Here is my code:

```
$jobids = [];
$markerpositions = [];
$jobpinlink = [];
$jobtitle = [];

foreach ($searchquery as $value) {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($value);

    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $stmt->close();

    $conn->close(); 


    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $position = ''.$row['joblat'].','.$row['joblng'].'';

        array_push($jobids, $row['jobunique']);
        array_push($markerpositions, $position);
        array_push($jobpinlink, $row['jobtypecolor']);
        array_push($jobtitle, $row['jobtitle']);

/*      $jobids[] = $row['jobunique'];  
        $markerpositions[] = $position;
        $jobpinlink[] = $row['jobtypecolor'];
        $jobtitle[] = $row['jobtitle'];
*/
    }   

    print_r($jobids); <- The first time it runs thrugh I get the IDs
}

print_r($jobids); <- Here the array is empty or not existing
```

The *$searchquery* is an array of mysql querys. I tested the mysql-querys I tested the script with and they are valid, so that can´t be the problem. Can someone please explain to me why the *$jobids*-array in the end is empty?

Comment: Instead of a bunch of unrelated arrays, why not one array that you push in multiple associative arrays? This makes it a ton easier to work with: `array_push($jobs, $row)` or more generically `$jobs[] = $row`. Even better, fetch it all at once with `fetch_all` if that's what you want anyway, skip the loop unless you're explicitly transforming the data.

Comment: Because further in the script I need to find congruent ID´s and work with the markerpositions by itself.

Comment: You can still iterate over the full result set and pull out the necessary IDs. I'd grab them all, then post-process the results to compute those, then move on. Having parallel arrays is asking for nasty, hard to debug issues when things get out of sync, or you need to delete/re-order records. It's a bad habit to get into.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but that´s not my problem. If i only use the $jobids array, the information either doesn´t get pushed into the array. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I can't see any problem with the way you're pushing into the arrays.

Comment: Is `$jobids` the only array that's having problems?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: Why do you have the empty strings at the beginning and end of `''.$row['joblat'].','.$row['joblng'].''`? I see people write this occasionally, and no one can ever tell me why they do that, instead of just writing `$position = $row['joblat'].','.$row['joblng'];`

Comment: if the `$jobids` array is the only one empty, `$row['jobunique']` might be returning an empty value there. Are you sure there's anything in that field?

Comment: I queryed the mysql-query`s in phpadmin and it gave the values back and in the first pring_r($jobids), inside the foreach-loop, it shows the values of the first run. Only the second print_r shows nothing... - thanks for the help

Comment: If I only use one query it works! - I tryed it with two querys and the array stays empty - but both querys are valid and give information back

Comment: How do you populate `$searchquery`? Did you try to do a `var_dump()` on `$searchquery`?

Comment: Haha - it was "$conn->close();" in the middle of the foreach-loop... I can´t believe it =)